# Boot a docker container from PXE

Tags: linux, docker

I would like to migrate an application server to a docker container. I currently have a PXE environment which i usually use to install new server and all necessary application and content.

Is there a way to get create a docker image that boots from PXE. After the install, them commit and save the image?

Thanks

Comment: You could consider PXE booting one of the OSes specially designed to run Docker containers. For example CoreOS or Project Atomic (from Redhat).

Answer (score 0):

If you can install a new server with the necessary application and content then you can certainly also install docker and your image. It would look something like this:

1. Install docker (client/server)
2. Use `docker load` to load your image from a tar file.
3. You can now do `docker run` on your image.

To save the image to a tar file use `docker save`.

Comment: Could you add more detail? I'm not sure that this explains how to set up PXE boot for the client containers.